# Multiplying each pixel by scale factor

Tags: c, function, pixel, multiplication

```
void scale_brightness( uint8_t array[],
               unsigned int cols,
               unsigned int rows,
               double scale_factor )
{
    for (int x = 0; x < rows; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < cols; y++)
        {
            array[x] = ceil(scale_factor * array[x]);
            array[y] = ceil(scale_factor * array[y]);
            if (array[x] >= 255 && array[y] >= 255)
            {
                array[x] = 255;
                array[y] = 255;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So this function is supposed to multiply each pixel in an image by a scale factor.  But for some reason, it's not working.  I can't find whats wrong with it.  Would anybody be able to help me out with it?

Comment: I'm not sure if this does what you think it does.  array[x] will continue to increase for however big y is, and each array[y] value will continue to increase for every iteration of x.  Is this supposed to be a two-dimensional array? Because it's not.

Answer (score 1):

Just unroll the loops on paper and you'll see what's happening...

1st iteration (x = 0, y = 0)

```
array[0] = ceil(scale_factor * array[0]);
array[0] = ceil(scale_factor * array[0]);
if (array[0] >= 255 && array[0] >= 255)
{
    array[0] = 255;
    array[0] = 255;
}
```

Already this is nonsensical, you're doing the same operation twice on the same element and then your if statement checks for the same condition twice on the same element, to then assign 255 twice to that same value.

2nd iteration (x = 0, y = 1)

```
array[0] = ceil(scale_factor * array[0]);
array[1] = ceil(scale_factor * array[1]);
if (array[0] >= 255 && array[1] >= 255)
{
    array[0] = 255;
    array[1] = 255;
}
```

So now you're setting element 0 again even though you just did it in the last iteration, but at least we're considering element 1 now.

By extrapolating we can see that the calculation will be applied for pixels 0 to max(cols, rows). Obviously your array of pixels has many more pixels than that, probably (cols * rows) pixels, so your algorithm ignores most pixels but is applied many times for some pixels, and that's basically why it doesn't work.

Comment: I would surmise that at the end of the of both loops, he has an array of values that equal 255, depending on the scale factor.

Answer (score 0):

Consider `array[x] = ceil(scale_factor * array[x]);`. If `array[x]` is 255 and `scale_factor` is 1.1, then that would be like `array[x] = 281;`. This is an overflow (281 is too large to fit in an unsigned 8-bit integer). C will discard the highest bits that don't fit, so it would be like `array[x] = 25;`.

Now consider `if(array[x] >= 255) array[x] = 255;`. Because it's working with unsigned 8-bit integers (that can only store values in the range from 0 to 255); it's only possible for `(array[x] >= 255)` to be true when `array[x]` contains the value 255. It would be equivalent to `if(array[x] == 255) array[x] = 255;`, which actually does nothing at all. Your `if (array[x] >= 255 && array[y] >= 255) {` code has the same problem - it does nothing.

Now read Asik's answer - he's right too. You're doing the same broken calculation multiple times on each pixel; and it's going to end up being a bit like a pseudo-random number generator.